# How can I block the database with mysqli in php to avoid another transactions in a script execution?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have to execute a set of prepared queries to load data in the DB (this load data dealys about 3 hours), and I'm searching the way of blocking the database while the script is executing because if other client executes any update or insert is possible that the info integrity will be break.

How can I do this?.

Thanks.

Comment: this is called maintenance of site. Just down the website for few mins or hours as per your requirement with a message "We are under maintenance".

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly, by "block" you mean terminate your connection so that no other queries can take place. Here is how you terminate your connection in MySQLi:

for MySQLi Procedural:

```
mysqli_close($conn);
```

for MySQLi Object-oriented:

```
$conn->close();
```

In both cases, `$conn` is the variable that stored the connection made.

In terms of security, I don't see this being an issue because it would only be a security issue if someone had access to your $conn object, and that object is safely stored in your PHP code. Well how safe depends on so many other factors, but I hope I at least answered your initial question :)

Comment: is possible  thaht two clients open a connection? or while the first client open a conexion, the second client cant open the conexion?

Comment: User want to execute the queries itself. `i have execute a set of prepared queries`

Comment: @eslop Your code is done in a `php` page, which means that it is done on your server. Two files can be activated about the same time sure, but a database has its own mechanisms for queuing which actions are done first. If your php file opens a connection, that just means you opened a connection between YOUR server and YOUR database, and wouldn't by itself open your database up for hackers, UNLESS you have some bad code elsewhere that creates a backdoor.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is called "table *locking*". You may read it up on google.

You may lock either entire table or a certain row, depends on your need.

After locking a table, no other client will be able to do a locked operation on it. You may start reading from here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-lock-modes.html

Comment: A believe the user is new to coding and wasn't referring to that specifically, but was concerned and confused about what happens when a connection is opened in a php script, possibly thinking a door opened for other users to hack.